# How to detect Safari (Iphone) browser In php?

Tags: php, safari, user-agent

I'm trying to detect the Safari browser using a method described in [w3docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/php/browser-detection.html).

I've tried ,

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

function getBrowser()
 {
   $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   $browser = "N/A";

   $browsers = [
     '/msie/i' => 'Internet explorer',
     '/firefox/i' => 'Firefox',
     '/safari/i' => 'Safari',
     '/chrome/i' => 'Chrome',
     '/edge/i' => 'Edge',
     '/opera/i' => 'Opera',
     '/mobile/i' => 'Mobile browser',
   ];

   foreach ($browsers as $regex => $value) {
     if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
       $browser = $value;
     }
   }

   return $browser;
 }
 $agent = getBrowser();
echo $agent;
?>
```

it returns chrome for chrome, mobile browser for mobile browser , but not for safari. Is there no way to detect the Safari (Iphone) browser?

Anyone is welcome to share any knowledge/help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to shortcut your loop, so that it exits as soon as it finds a matching value:

```
foreach ($browsers as $regex => $value) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And then you might want a default if nothing is found:

```
foreach ($browsers as $regex => $value) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        return $value;
    }
}
return 'unknown';
```

Otherwise, you'll traverse the whole list every time, and (probably) always match the last one "mobile" because it's likely to also appear in the string.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried your suggestion, [my code](https://pastebin.com/jrakgFFE)
But  Now It returns only safari

Comment: i mean it doesn't work. it returns safari on all browsers

Comment: Edit your question and post the updated version of your function.

Comment: it returns chrome for chrome, mobile browser for mobile browser , but not for safari

Comment: Post the complete user agent string for your IOS Safari.